# Como verificar se dois Drawable são iguais?

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

Boa noite !
   Estou com dificuldades para recuperar a imagem atual do meu imageView android. Ele é um Image de favoritar para o usuário(dar like), e quero que quando o usuário clique nessa imagem, eu verifique se a imagem atual é = a um icone de coração sem preenchimento, se sim então executar a função de curtir, caso contrário, executar a função de descurtit. No código atual a validação sempre sai como FALSO, mesmo quando deve ser VERDADEIRO e a variavel drawable está recebendo = ""

```
public void favoritar(){

    Versiculos favoritar = new Versiculos();
    SharedPreferencias preferencias = new SharedPreferencias(getApplicationContext());

    Drawable drawable = imLike.getDrawable();

    if (drawable.equals(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border)){
        //Curtindo
        favoritar.curtirVersiculo(idVersiculo, preferencias.getCHAVE_ID());
        imLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);

    } else {
        //Descurtindo
        favoritar.descurtirVersiculo(idVersiculo, preferencias.getCHAVE_ID());
        imLike.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);

    }
}
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está a comparar um Drawable com um inteiro(`R.drawable.ic_favorite_border` é um inteiro).

Por outro lado, para comparar Drawables, tem de usar o objecto retornado pelo método `getConstantState()`.

Comece por obter o Drawable correspondente ao id `R.drawable.ic_favorite_border`

```
Drawable favoriteBorder = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border);
```

depois, faça a comparação assim:

```
if (drawable.getConstantState().equals(favoriteBorder.getConstantState())){

}
```

Comment: Funcinou exatamente como eu precisava, ainda, como estou tratando a ação do click chamando um método e não uma ação que recebesse a view Imagem, eu precisei manter a variavel drawable = imLike.getDrawable() (conforme você mesmo previu na resolução acima), muito obrigado!